# Bugzilla: Large value bug ID numbers

Tags: numbers, bugzilla

IS there a way to tell how large bug numbers can get in Bugzilla? In other words, how can I find the upper limit? Is it regulated by the processor or the tables? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what the abstract data type `MEDIUMSERIAL` is on the database.

The abstract schema is in `Bugzilla::DB::Schema`, and the corresponding implementation is in the appropriate `Bugzilla::DB::Schema::*` module.

On MySQL, `MEDIUMSERIAL` is a `mediumint`, so the largest value for `bug_id` is 8388607.

There's only one known Bugzilla instance with as many as 1M rows in `bugs`, so I'm not aware of any drive to increase the size in the vanilla source.

http://lpsolit.wordpress.com/bugzilla-usage-worldwide/

At Yahoo!, where we have more than 5 million rows in `bugs`, we've already increased `bug_id` to a 4-byte signed integer, so our new maximum `bug_id` is 2147483647.